# as3 access stage info from subclasses and packages

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scope, closures, stage

I am trying to make a game in as3.  All my code is here https://github.com/raphydaphy/LightStage/ and when I try to run it, I get some errors:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at backend/prepGame()[~/LightStage Beta/src/backend.as:412]
at LightStage/keyHandler()[~/LightStage Beta/src/LightStage.as:99]
```

Which is basically this line (in backend.as, which is a package:

```
LightStage.instance.gotoAndStop(2);
```

Which is called here (in LightStage.as, which is the document class):

```
G.vars.backend.prepGame();
```

I know that the problem is that I can't access the gotoAndStop method of the LightStage document class. I have searched far on so and found nothing.

I have been able to get access to the stage with this written in the document class (LightStage.as):

```
G.vars._stage = stage;
```

However, trying to change the frame of the main timeline, as I said above, fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just as it sounds.  Use the Debug Panels (Call Stack & Variables), and you should see what the code is complaining about.

Because you're accessing `LightStage` as a Static class, I've added a local variable to give the class scope in the debugger.  As you can see, `instance` is a null object.

[image: Snapshot of the code at 414]

One step further back, and into `LightStage.keyhandler()` and you'll find the same evidence: `instance` was never set.

Before I get into a solution, please note the following:

- While `LightStage` is your document class, it is also your `MainTimeline` (a.k.a. `root`)
- [`Stage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) is not equal to [`MainTimeline`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)
- AS3 has no static classes, only static properties.  Therefore, unless a method or property is explicitly declared to be static, you cannot access it without first instantiating the class.  This is why you only see 2 properties on our `localLightStage` variable.  From the `backend` perspective, those are the only static properties available.

You have [a number of avenues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920209/how-to-access-a-public-array-vector-from-another-class) available to you for getting to the data you, but given the maturity of your app, the less unbalancing solutions would be:

1. Make the properties and methods you're accessing from `backend` static.
2. Pass a reference of the instantiated `LightStage` into `backend` and store that as a variable.

In your case, I'd go with the latter.

After line 68 in `LightStage` add the following: `G.vars._root = this;`

Replace `prepGame()` with the following:

```
public function prepGame(): void
{
    G.vars._root.setFrame(2); // Go to second frame 'LightStage is starting..'

    var startGameTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1); // prepare a one second timer to start the game
    startGameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, G.vars._root.game); // create a listner for the timer
    startGameTimer.start(); // start the timer
}
```

That'll fix your current issue.  After that, you'll find additional errors.

Replace line 142 in backend.as (which has a run-on condition) which looks like:

`if (G.vars.lines[lineNum].G.vars._stage &&`

And replace with:

`if (G.vars.lines[lineNum] &&`

On line 256 of `backend.as` you're accessing `G.vars.badges.checkBadges();` however, on line 50 of `LightStage`, you're replacing your instantiated class with an array: `G.vars.badges = [];`.  Delete that line.

Also, line 256 won't be able to access that function as long as you've designated it to be `private`.  Change line 58 of `badges.as` to: `public function checkBadges(): void`

Comment: Thank you so much! You fixed my problem !!
I don't have enough rep but i would upvote if i could :(